# How to get cell address from Find function in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find

How do I get cell address using Find function.

Here's the code

```
Dim Found As Range

Set Found = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells.Find(What:="test", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    ' do something
End If
```

When I debug the code, "Found" variable contain a "string" instead of cell address.

Comment: `Found` variable doesn't contain a `String`, you've declared it `As Range`, so it contains a `Range` object reference. [A `Range` has an `Address` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) - use it. The string content you're seeing is the range's `Value`, which is the *default property* (i.e. the member that's implicitly referred to when no member is specified).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems you can just use `found.address` even though it shows as string. The below code worked for me.

```
Sub findCellAddress()

    Dim ra As Range

    Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="fff", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Not found")
        Else
        MsgBox (ra.Address)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Find` can return `Nothing`, so tacking `.Address` onto the end of it is [just begging for a run-time error 91](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel-vba%5D+find+error+91).  `Find` should always be set to a temporary `Range` object and tested against `Nothing` before any of the properties are used.

Comment: Hi @nightcrawler23 thanks for your feedback. Is there any way to get the row and column from "ra.Address" seperately? I want to apply it into cells selection (Ex: Cells(1,2))

Comment: A Range has row and column properties. So you can use ra.Row and ra.Column to get the values. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: @RandyAdhitama when you type the `.` dot after `ra`, there should be a little in-place dropdown (that's *IntelliSense*) showing you all the available members. Explore a bit. Research the members online when you're not sure what they do - *everything* is thoroughly documented. You can also use the *object browser* (F2 in the VBE editor) to browse all the types and members in all referenced libraries.

Answer (score 5):

I could not find this anywhere on the internet.
This code will give you the row and the column.

```
Dim ThisPos As Range
With Range("A1:J100")
    Set ThisPos = .Find(What:="List_Position", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not ThisPos Is Nothing Then
        Cell_Add = Split(ThisPos.Address, "$")
        ThisCol = Cell_Add(1)
        ThisRow = Cell_Add(2)
    End If
End With
```

Comment: This answer is useful but could use some work. You could put in the variable type declarations but also I believe ThisRow actually gets the column and ThisColumn gets the row.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you reference style of the cell address.

```
 Dim SValue As Range
   With Range("D1:D100")

    Set SValue = .Find(What:="Searched Value", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    If Not SValue Is Nothing Then
        Cell_Split_R = Split(SValue.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), "R")
        Cell_Split_C = Split(Cell_Split_R(1), "C")
        SCol = Cell_Split_C(0)
        SRow = Cell_Split_C(1)
        
    End If
End With
```